# All HDD activity randomly freezes for 1 minute once a day on average

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze

Roughly once a day all my hard drives stop reading or writing. All currently active programs still work like they normally should, except when they try to load or save anything. Chrome, for example, will still show currently loaded pages, but opon loading a new page it will be stuck on "loading cache". Activity will resume like nothing happened ~1 minute later. Due to this no error logs are generated.

### What I tried

Reading windows events, no events occur at the time the hard drives freeze.
Ran HD Tune and checked:

- S.M.A.R.T. status of all disks, no errors or warnings for any of the disks.
- Ran an error scan for all disks, no errors reported.

Ran a virus scan, nothing found.
Ran mdsched to check my RAM
Recorded the event in resource monitor, hard drive usage went to 0%, hard drive response time went off the charts for all drives. This happened for both disks currently in use, a third disk which was spun down did not report anything special.

### Specs

**OS**: Windows 7
**CPU**: amd fx8350
**GPU**: amd msi r9 270x hawk edition (msi overclock)
**MB**: ASRock 970 Extreme4
**Memory**: crucial ballistix DDR3 4x4gb (16gb), 1833MHz clock running at 1600MHz
**HDD**:
232GB Maxtor 6V250F0
119GB M4-CT128M4SSD2
1863GB Western Digital WDC WD20EZRX-00D8PB0

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Does this happen at the same time each day? Or after the computer has been on for a specific period of time?

Comment: @CharlieRB The problem doesn't occur at a set time each day, it has happened during the day, and night. Problem also happend just after booting, and just before shutting down, under heavy loads and whilst doing almost nothing at all.

Comment: If you haven't already, run virus and malware scans to ensure there isn't something messing with your system. Then run other hardware diagnostics. Checking the memory and motherboard would be a good idea. An error with one of those can slow things to a crawl. Despite the hard drive tools you have already used, I would disconnect all but one drive at a time to see if you can identify if it is specific to one drive.

Comment: What are you using for antivirus? Does it use real-time scanning? If so, try disabling real time scanning temporarily. Obviously don't do anything questionable on the internet during this time.

Comment: Do you have any services that perform automated SMART testing (not just reading the accumulated stats, but actually testing the disk)?

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does it happen?

Comment: @CharlieRB Already ran an virus scan, memory check reports no errors. I don't know how to run a diagnostic of my motherboard, but my on board debugger (dr debug) gives no errors. Disconnecting all hard drives but one is possible, but will take 1 to 2 days per drive to verify, as the error occurs roughly only once a day.

Comment: @LSxCPU I'm using Avira, real time scanning is enabled. I will try disabling the real time scanning.

Comment: @FrankThomas I downloaded and installed CrystalDiskInfo, which is currently monitoring the S.M.A.R.T. status.